# Document query selector returns undefined in react

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to build a toggle sidebar. when I click on the button the class list of `.m-toggle` should be updated. But react gives me an error

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null"

Here is my code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
// import Sidebar from '../Components/Sidebar'
import AppleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Apple'
import DashboardIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Dashboard'
import PeopleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/People'
import NotificationsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Notifications'
import SettingsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Settings'
import HelpIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Help'
import img from '../Assets/img/keval.jpg'

function toggleMenu() {
  let toggle = document.querySelector('.m-toggle')
  toggle.classList.toggle('m-active')
}

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="m-body">
        <div className="m-container">
          {/* -------Sidebar Start------- */}
          <div className="m-navigation">
            <ul style={{ padding: '0' }}>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <span className="m-icon">
                    <AppleIcon className="muicon" />
                  </span>
                  <span className="m-title">
                    <h2>Brand Name</h2>
                  </span>
                </a>
                <hr style={{ color: 'white' }} />
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <span className="m-icon">
                    <DashboardIcon className="muicon" />
                  </span>
                  <span className="m-title">Dashboard</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <span className="m-icon">
                    <PeopleIcon className="muicon" />
                  </span>
                  <span className="m-title">Employees</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <span className="m-icon">
                    <NotificationsIcon className="muicon" />
                  </span>
                  <span className="m-title">Notification</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <span className="m-icon">
                    <HelpIcon className="muicon" />
                  </span>
                  <span className="m-title">Help</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <span className="m-icon">
                    <SettingsIcon className="muicon" />
                  </span>
                  <span className="m-title">Setting</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          {/* --------Side BAr End--------- */}
          <div className="m-main">
            <div className="m-topbar">
              <div className="m-toggle" onClick={toggleMenu()}>
                f
              </div>
              <div className="m-search">
                <label>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Search here" />
                </label>
              </div>
              <div className="user">
                <img src={img} alt="no img" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Main
```

You can see the code where `onclick` class list should be updated but it is not updating.

Comment: _"Document query selector returns undefined..."_ (which won't ever be the case) but then _"Type Error: Can not read property ClassList Of Null"_. The title should give a proper summary of the actual problem and not a _"might describe the situation good enough"_

Comment: It might be that in a stylesheet you use `display: none` for `.m-toggle` or a parent element. If you want to get the element via `querySelector` you need to use `visibility: hidden`

Comment: It's because you do this `onClick={toggleMenu()}` which calls the function immediately even before mount. You should use `onClick={toggleMenu}`

Comment: ... and as the click event is fired on the .m-toggle element, you won't need to use querySelector, because `this` already refers to the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem I see is that you are not passing a function reference in onClick, but doing a function call instead:

```
<div className="m-toggle" onClick={toggleMenu()}>
```

Either remove the parentheses after toggleMenu:

```
<div className="m-toggle" onClick={toggleMenu}>
```

or pass it as an inline arrow function:

```
<div className="m-toggle" onClick={() => toggleMenu()}>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `toggleMenu()` method during component render which you shouldn't do.
So when your component tries to render, it calls `toggleMenu` method and returns null for `m-toggle query selector`. you can either bind function reference or use arrow function.

```
<div className="m-toggle" onClick={toggleMenu}>
```

**OR**

```
<div className="m-toggle" onClick={() => toggleMenu()}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Several problems:

1. React onClick expects a function but you are invoking `toggleMenu` instead. It should be `onClick={toggleMenu}` or  `onClick={()=>toggleMenu()}`
2. You should be managing the className using state instead of using `document.querySelector()` and modifying the element yourself.